# Eclipse PHP: Multi-Line String, Not Auto-Indenting on Return

Tags: php, eclipse, ide

Original code:

`$sql .= "
                LEFT OUTER JOIN";`

Hit "enter" after "JOIN", what I want:

`$sql .= "
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                (cursor)";`

What I get:

`$sql .= "
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
(cursor)";`

How to fix?

EDIT: Also, Eclipse is inserting 4 spaces instead of a tab even though my tab settings don't say to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really the perfect solution, but makes things a little bit better (tested in Eclipse PDT 6.2):
Under preferences go to `PHP > Editor > Typing` and check `"Tab key indents current line"`